# How can I use KVC to set attributes of Core Data objects?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, kvc

I'm working with a core data entity that has four date attributes - syncDate, historicSyncDate, etc.

Is there a way I can write a single method that would take a NSString name of one of these attributes and assign a proper date for it?

Ex:

```
-(void)updateDate:(NSDate*) date forAttribute:(NSString*)attribute forService:(Service*)service
{
    //based on attribute name, set service.syncDate or service.historicSyncDate, etc
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

```
[service setValue:date forKey:attribute];
```

From the "NSManagedObject Class Reference":

> `setValue:forKey:`
>   Sets the specified property of the receiver to the
>   specified value.
>
> ...
>   If key identifies a
>   to-one relationship, relates the object specified by value to the
>   receiver, unrelating the previously related object if there was one.
>   Given a collection object and a key that identifies a to-many
>   relationship, relates the objects contained in the collection to the
>   receiver, unrelating previously related objects if there were any.
>
> This method is overridden by NSManagedObject to access the managed
>   object’s generic dictionary storage unless the receiver’s class
>   explicitly provides key-value coding compliant accessor methods for
>   key.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do...

```
-(void)updateDate:(NSDate*) date forAttribute:(NSString*)attribute forService:(Service*)service
{
    [service setValue:date forKey:attribute];
}
```

Assuming `Service` is a sub-class of `NSManagedObject`